# validar datos de un array con ajax en js

Tags: javascript

quiero hacer una validación en js para no repetir datos en la base de datos, y estoy teniendo un error y necesito que me aclaro por favor para poder resolver el problema lo tengo en este else if,

```
if (existeImeibd(imei1)) {

        $('#imei_errort').removeClass("d-none");
        $('#imeiel_error').addClass("d-none");
        $('#imei_error').addClass("d-none");
        $('#imeieb_error').removeClass("d-none");

      }
```

en la función recibo un `si` si existe el dato en la base de datos y no si no existe aqui me funciona todo bien me llega el si si existe y el no si no existe pero no activa los errores y envia el dato al array

```
function existeImeibd(imei1){

  $.ajax({
    url:"../ajax/productos.php?op=existe_imei",
    method:"POST",
    data:{imei1:imei1},
    success: function(data){

      if(data === "si" ){
        return true;

      }else{
        return false;
      }

      }

  });

}
```

quiero que si es si active los errores y se detenga hasta que envié un no

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo una llamada asíncrona y el método `success` se ejecuta cuando se resuelve la petición al servidor. Por lo tanto, cuando eso ocurre la función `existeImeibd` ya ha sido ejecutada y es por eso que el `if` nunca se cumple.

Cuando una función no hace un `return` javascript implícitamente hace un `return undefined`.
Y el `callback` que especificas en el `success` se ejecutará en un futuro cuando el servidor haya devuelto la respuesta. Se ejecutará fuera del contexto de `existeImeibd`.

El flujo de tu función es este para que lo entiendas.

1. Se ejecuta `existeImeibd`
2. Se hace la petición `ajax`
3. Se registra el callback de `success` que será llamado cuando se resuelva la petición
4. Acaba la ejecución de `existeImeibd`
5. Se evalua `if (existeImeibd(imei1)) {}` como no se devuelve (se devuelve `undefined` implícitamente pero es un valor [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)) y no se cumple.
6. En x tiempo el servidor devuelve la respuesta
7. Sino se está ejecutando otra función en el callstack se ejecuta el `callback` `success`

Puedes usar promesas o añadir tu código en el `success`.

```
function existeImeibd(imei1) {

  $.ajax({
    url: "../ajax/productos.php?op=existe_imei",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      imei1: imei1
    },
    success: function(data) {

      if (data === "si") {

          $('#imei_errort').removeClass("d-none");
          $('#imeiel_error').addClass("d-none");
          $('#imei_error').addClass("d-none");
          $('#imeieb_error').removeClass("d-none");

      } 

    }

  });
}
```